# Stream microphone to a server? Flash or Silverlight?

Tags: ruby, silverlight, actionscript-3, rtmp, rtmfp

I'm looking to build an app, which will at least in part require audio streamed live from a client machine to a server.  I'd ideally like to run a linux server, the rest of my app is written in Ruby, so bonus points for a Ruby-centric set up, and I would like to avoid the Flash Media Server and/or Red5 if possible.  (It just seems like a lot of software that I'm not really going to use.)

Bottom line -- can I stream from Flash without using RTMP/RTMFP?  If not, can I receive that in a Ruby-based app?  Is this worth even attempting in Silverlight?

Comment: @The_asMan -- do you know of any ruby libraries for RTMP/RTMFP?  or am i on my own?

Answer (score 0):

> Bottom line -- can I stream from Flash without using RTMP/RTMFP?

Yes. The ActionScript 3 API offers two other types of realtime communcation:

- XML Sockets via [flash.net.XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html)
- Binary Sockets via [flash.net.Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html)

Here are some implementation insights from unrelated questions and answers:

- [Flex - XMLSocket truncates the final closing tag of the XML - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363870/flex-xmlsocket-truncates-the-final-closing-tag-of-the-xml-why)
- [How to transmit live video over a Socket using Flex / ActionScript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445297/how-to-transmit-live-video-over-a-socket-using-flex-actionscript-3)